# How can I work with the real file behind a symlink?

Tags: linux, bash, symbolic-link

I have a file and a symlink:

```
file: ~/${USER_HOME}/blabla/.cheatsheet
symlink: ~/.cheatsheet (is linked to file above)
```

Now in my script I do some operations with the file, e.g. add a line and sort the file alphabetically and move it:

```
addOneCommand() {
  file"=~/.cheatsheet"
  # add it to the file
  echo "${cmd}" >> "${file}"
  # sort file instantly
  cat "${file}" | sort > "${file}".tmp
  mv "${file}".tmp "${file}"
}
```

But the real file behind the symlink doesn't get affected by the script (e.g. not sorted alphabetically). 
What can I do to work with "symlinked files" in bash scripts?

Thanks.

Comment: Note: `file"=~/.cheatsheet"` is not going to work.

Comment: You may find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665/how-to-resolve-symbolic-links-in-a-shell-script or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29789204/bash-how-to-get-real-path-of-a-symlink?rq=1 or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167631/finding-the-original-file-of-a-symbolic-link or https://serverfault.com/questions/76042/find-out-symbolic-link-target-via-command-line of interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is, that you create a new file `${file}.tmp`, that is now **not** a symlink, then rename.

You might try

```
cat "${file}".tmp >"${file}"
rm "${file}".tmp
```

instead of

```
mv "${file}".tmp "${file}"
```

If you don't mind the race condition.

**P.S.:** If I understand your intention correctly, you might want `sort -u` instead of plain `sort`

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're using `mv`, which will replace the symlink.

You can use a number of other approaches (see Eugen Rieck's answer for one), but fundamentally, you need to *reuse* the symlink, not *replace* it.

`sponge` is a good tool that will also allow you to remove handling of the `*.tmp` file as well:

With a file `a`, that is symlinked from `b`:

```bsh
$ echo -e "3\n1\n2" > a
$ ln -s a b
$ ls -l
total 1
-rw-r--r-- 1 attie attie 6 Mar  5 15:44 a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 attie attie 1 Mar  5 15:44 b -> a
```

You can sort and rewrite `a` via `b`, without affecting the symlink:

```bsh
$ cat b | sort | sponge b
$ ls -l
total 1
-rw-r--r-- 1 attie attie 6 Mar  5 15:44 a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 attie attie 1 Mar  5 15:44 b -> a
$ cat b
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the real file behind the symlink using the `readlink` or `realpath` commands.